# MySQL and HTML database reference in URL link

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I'm trying to have an image link, where for a folder is defined by my users setting it in their settings folder.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
if (strpos($current_user_meta['UserRank'], 'Admiral ') !== false ) {   
   // get the user class somehow
   $userclass = $current_user_meta['userclass'];     
  echo '<img alt="Admiral" src="../images/ranks/".$userclass."/admiral.png" /> ';
} else {
  echo '';
}
?>
```

The problem is that the image link doesn't pick up the folder which is defined by `$userclass` and everything afterwords.

So any ideas what I can do? I've tried `.$userclass.` which didn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the quotation marks:

```
echo '<img alt="Admiral" src="../images/ranks/' . $userclass . '/admiral.png" /> ';
```

Comment: @user3135072 If this answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer.